# Finding a function of a specific package in RStudio help pane

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a way to access the function of a specific package in the help pane of RStudio?

Let's say I want to look up `count()` from the `dplyr` package:

- Looking for `count` in the help pane of RStudio results in a huge list of search results. This search is equivalent to `??count` from the console.
- In the console, I could write `?dplyr::count`. Is there an equivalent in the help pane of RStudio?

Comment: What about F1? write `count` in the console and press `F1`

Comment: This only works when code completion can select the correct package. It does not work e.g. after loading `dplyr` and then trying to look up `filter()` from the `stats`package because of `dplyr` masking it.

Comment: It shows all functions from packages, that are installed. They dont have to be loaded, but it would not find a function from a package which was not installed yet.

Comment: If the function is masked by another package, you cannot see it. Even if both packages are installed: `stats` is loaded on startup by default but you cannot see it typing `filter` in the console whenever `dplyr` is loaded too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### RStudio HelpPane

Today the RStudio java code for help Window (see -> [HelpPane.java:364](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/gwt/src/org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/help/HelpPane.java#L364)) does not support the ability to search a specific package context. It could but it would require modifications to [HelpSearch.java:67](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/gwt/src/org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/help/search/HelpSearch.java#L67)

```
./rstudio/src/gwt/src/org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/help

./HelpPane.java:364:
toolbar.addRightWidget(searchProvider_.get().getSearchWidget());
./search/HelpSearch.java:67:
public Widget getSearchWidget()
```

### RStudio

Today, in RStudio you can do a help lookup via the R console and reflect the results in the RStudio help window. The workaround is to type `?dplyr::count` in the R Console and have this reflected in the RStudio help window.

[image]

I hope the above information if useful, and points you in the right direction. My sense is you'll need to request or change RStudio window behaviour.

---

### R Help Observations:

If you wish to look up a specific function in a package you can use the following syntax:

`help(count, package="dplyr")`

Personally, I also recommend using the `sos` library which adds `???` this enables access to the `findfn()` and `???` which enables you to access `RSiteSearch()` and search across all CRAN libraries for a function.

```
> require(sos)
> 
> ???count
found 7174 matches;  retrieving 20 pages, 400 matches.
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 

Downloaded 399 links in 244 packages.
```

The above syntax is referenced in the R documentation. https://www.r-project.org/help.html

#### R Help: help() and ?

The `help()` function and `?` help operator in R provide access to the documentation pages for R functions, data sets, and other objects, both for packages in the standard R distribution and for contributed packages. To access documentation for the standard lm (linear model) function, for example, enter the command `help(lm)` or `help("lm")`, or `?lm` or `?"lm"` (i.e., the quotes are optional).

***To access help for a function in a package that’s not currently loaded, specify in addition the name of the package: For example, to obtain documentation for the `rlm()` (robust linear model) function in the MASS package, `help(rlm, package="MASS")`.***

Standard names in R consist of upper- and lower-case letters, numerals (0-9), underscores (_), and periods (.), and must begin with a letter or a period. To obtain help for an object with a non-standard name (such as the help operator ?), the name must be quoted: for example, `help('?')` or `?"?"`.

You may also use the help() function to access information about a package in your library — for example, `help(package="MASS")` — which displays an index of available help pages for the package along with some other information.

Help pages for functions usually include a section with executable examples illustrating how the functions work. You can execute these examples in the current R session via the `example()` command: e.g., `example(lm)`.

Comment: Indeed your answer was useful and explained many details I didn't know. So I upvoted it. – But it did not answer my question: "Is there an equivalent in the help pane of RStudio?"

Comment: @petzi Just to be clear here you want to map '?dplyr::count' to 'help(count, package="dplyr")' ? I ask as from my perspective I would use 'help(count, package="dplyr")' to get the desired help. It sounds like you want to extend the shorthand '?' to search in a library for a function. So I know of no standard way but I can see how you might modify the help '?' function to do that. –

Comment: I would like to map '?dplyr::count' to a command in the help pane of RStudio itself. Currently, so far as I know, you can't do that in one single step. You have to type `dplyr` into the package pane, select it, and only then you can type `count`. -- The reason for my desire to find a method for a single command in the RStudio pane: I find it inconvenient to change panes or to scroll down a list with all those packages where `count` is mentioned.

Comment: @petzi - I looked at the RStudio code to see if this was a quick fix. To do what you propose in the RStudio help window will require code changes to RStudio. Today, the functionality is supported via piping the help request from the console to the help pane.

Comment: I think this settles my issue. Even it is not the solution I was hoping for, I know now that I would have to ask RStudio developers for a feature request. -- Admittedly user2554330 was the first to claim that it cannot be done without a change in RStudio, it was only you who convinced me by looking into the RStudio code. So I think it is fair to give you the bounty.

Comment: @petzi - I admit I was hoping a quick fix might be in order. As it stands I am looking through the code to see how complicated the fix is. The downside is I had to go and download and build RStudio, install QT to build it etc. `https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/wiki/RStudio-Development` and `https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/wiki/Installing-RStudio-Dependencies`. My sense is that your proposal is beneficial hence worth bringing up with RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing exactly equivalent to `?dplyr::count` as far as I can see (but of course you could just type that in the console if you really need it).

Something sort of close is to get any `dplyr` help page (e.g. by doing a search for `"dplyr"`), then going to the bottom of the page, and clicking on `Index`.  Alternatively, go to `Packages`, and scroll down to `dplyr`; clicking there gets you to the same place.  This a list of all `dplyr` help topics; scroll down (or use the letter index) to get to `count`.

Comment: I am not an expert but I do not understand the following: if you can call the right help page with eg. `?dplyr::count` from the console why should you not be able to call it from the help page as well? I assume that some regex is required.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question, but if I do, the answer is that help pages don't have any way to execute user-generated R code.  Nothing would stop RStudio from adding this capability, but we already have the console for that, so it doesn't make sense to do so.

Comment: The reason would be: To limit searches in the help pane of RStudio with just one command -- instead of calling the packages first, scroll down and click the ´index` link or to change constantly your attention from one pane to the other. Maybe nobody knows of a solution and/or there is really none, then your answer is the most correct one and I will give you the bounty. -- So let's wait some more days.

Answer (score 0):

Help home, then Packages, then dplyr, then count.